# Having a nightmare trying to compare whether two dates match in a React App

Tags: javascript, date

As the title says I am struggling to get this thing to work. I have looked at the similar posts on here and many reference MomentJS, which on their own site they advise against using it now.

```
 const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb')

 return loading ? <Spinner /> : 
 <Fragment>
    <div className="calendar_events">
      <p className="ce_title">Upcoming Events</p>
        {
          appointments.map(appointment => {
            let date = new Date(appointment.date).toLocaleDateString('en-gb')
            {console.log('date', typeof date)}
            {console.log('today', typeof today)}
            if(today == date) {
              <Appointment key={appointment._id} appointment={appointment} date={date}/>
            }        
          })
        }
    </div>
  </div>
</Fragment>
```

I have tried with moment but no success. I am now trying vanilla JS, when I console.log each date, today and an appointment date, they're the same. when I console.log the typeof these, they're both strings, but my if statement never runs.

I only want to call the  component for appointments that match todays date or any other given date on the calendar.

i realise I am recreating the wheel here, but this is more about learning and taking my mind off things than the actual end result.

I would be happy for any guidance as to what on Earth I am missing.

**Console output for typeof**

```
date string Calendar.js:39
today string Calendar.js:40
```

**Console output for each variable**

```
date 29/11/20 Calendar.js:39
today 29/11/20 Calendar.js:40 *2 as there are two demo appointments on this date.
```

I have also tried the **==** and **===** operators but nada.

Please send help, my sanity is lost.

**Edit**

I managed to get it working, I think with the help of @Uzair Ashraf.

It even appears to work more succinctly with the following code

```
{
          appointments.map(appointment => {
            let date = new Date(appointment.date).toLocaleDateString('en-gb')
            if(today === date) {
              return <Appointment key={appointment._id} appointment={appointment} />
            }
           })
        }
```

Comment: If you only want to compare the date, then *toDateString* is likely a better comparison. Where the types are the same (in this case, string) using `==` or `===` makes no difference. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a return statement.
Although if you don't have a fallback it will create an array with React elements and undefined.

I would recommend filtering through the array and then mapping

Edit: Also you seem to have an extra closing div tag. You also don't need the fragment

Edit2: You can split a date like this:

```
let date =  "2020-11-29T00:00:00.000Z"
date = date.split('T')[0]
```

```
 const today = new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-gb')

 return loading ? <Spinner /> : 
    <div className="calendar_events">
      <p className="ce_title">Upcoming Events</p>
        {
          appointments
           .filter(appointment => new Date(appointment.date).toLocaleDateString('en-gb') === today)
           .map(appointment => {
              return <Appointment key={appointment._id} appointment={appointment} date={new Date(appointment.date).toLocaleDateString('en-gb')}/>
            }        
          })
        }
  </div>
```

Comment: are you not returning two times??

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I know what a callback is but this is not what you did is callback lol more

Comment: filter and map take callbacks are arguments, the only reason you need an explicit return statement with map is because we're using curly braces in the map method call.
If you don't return anything then it will return an array with undefined

Comment: This actually makes some progress, it does however output the date format as "2020-11-29T00:00:00.000Z" though.

Comment: @AdamSackfield You can split that

Comment: @UzairAshraf - Yeah I can do the whole toLocaleDateString again inside the Appointment component. Seems a little redundant to have to do it twice. I guess it's moot as I don;'t need to show the date inside that component as long as I am sure I am only getting the correct appointmets passed through. Could you explain the logic of where I was going wrong, was it mainly missing the return statement?

Comment: Sure! @AdamSackfield higher order functions like map, filter, find, some, every, etc, take callback functions as arguments.  Basically calling the callback function on every single value in the array. So when you call map, you are mapping over the values, performing some action on those values, and returning them to be stored in a new array.
Normally you don't see the explicit return statement because single line arrow functions have an implicit return, like the filter method call in this example.
But when you use curly braces you must explicitly return your new value, like the react compone

Comment: @UzairAshraf Perfect. I love you my dude. I've only wasted 7 hours on this, buy hey that's seven hours not being depressed. Thanks

Comment: The only reason I can answer this quickly is because I did my 7 hours at one point with the same problem, don't sweat it, we all start somewhere @AdamSackfield

Comment: @Uzair Ashraf - That’s why I love the web dev community, everybody is willing to help if you’ve at least put in the time yourself to try everything you can. I don’t love to in this field but my React game isn’t as strong as my API building. So maybe one day I can get paid.